# Parse a email body for Salesforce Id

Tags: apex-email-service, string

I have created a email service wherein I have to check if the email body has the salesforce Id in it and If yes I have to get that Id.

I will always have Id in this format:

[Shipment] : **********

[Order] : ********

[Opty] : ***********

I will have these tags followed by the Ids in my email body.

The email body may have any text in it.

Please suggest!

Comment: This question doesn't show anything that you've attempted to implement for yourself for us to assist you with. One avenue you could attempt would be to use the [Pattern & Matcher classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm) to parse the body of the email for ID values using a Regular Expression pattern similar to this one, which matches on a 15 or 18 character ID for the User object (005). `005[0-9a-zA-Z]{12,15}`

Comment: I have actually found a solution for this. I am using a delimiter to separate my tag and SFDCID . I have used some functions from string class to achieve this. Thank you all for your suggestions!!

Answer (score 4):

I've actually written something like this before. Here's a pared down version of what you're looking for:

```
public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env) {
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String body = email.plainTextBody == null? (email.htmlBody == null? '': email.htmlBody.stripHtmlTags()): email.plainTextBody;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\p{Alnum}{15}\\p{Alnum}{3}?)');
    Matcher m = p.matcher(body);
    while(m.find())) {
        try {
            Id recordId = (Id)m.group(0);
            // Do something with the ID value
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // Not a valid Id after all...
        }
    }
    result.success = true;
    return result;
}
```